# How to generate Chart depending on multiple query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, charts

I don't know if u will understand what I mean but I hope this
Simply I want to generate chart from depending on data stored in SQL SERVER 2008 data base .. I did it but i have a problem

My data is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDkP3.png)

In line graph

I Want to draw graph which each line is depending to one result query
I Use this

```
SqlCommand territorycommand = new SqlCommand("select Terriotry,UCPVol,Forecast from ForecastTotal where Year = '" + year + "' or year = '" + year2 + "'", conn);
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        mydatareader = territorycommand.ExecuteReader();
                        while (mydatareader.Read())
                        {
                            chart1.Series["Forecast"].Points.AddXY(mydatareader.GetString(0), mydatareader.GetInt32(1));
                            chart1.Series["TotalAchievment"].Points.AddY(mydatareader.GetInt32(2));
                            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
                            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

                            chart1.Series["TotalAchievment"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                            chart1.Series["Forecast"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;


                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    conn.Close();
```

what I Want to draw the first line from year1 .. for example 2017 and second line from year2 for example 2019

Like Compering what i should do ?

Like this pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bij2m.png)

Red line is 2019 and black one is 2017

Comment: a) separate preparing the chart and the two series from reading the data! b) if you want to do anything with the x-vlues (the years, right??) don't add them as string but as numbers or DateTimes. c) add all points with addxy and use the same x-value! d) with only one point you can't expext any lines to show! e) when asking about charts it always help to add a sketch of what you want and/or what you have so far..

Comment: I edited the post and added the result which i want can u clear plz ?

Comment: Well, the x-values seem to com from 1st column which is a name? Worthless for real dates, obviously. But if you have all 12 rows that make up the months of a year you still can add them. Did you change the 2nd addY to an AddXY as I told you? What is missing then??

Comment: what about sql query .. i think it's wrong so it's like i want to get 2 query result do u understand what i want ? 
how can i make first XY for first part which get 2017 data and make second XY for second part which refer for 2019 data ?

Comment: SQL can be written in powerful and amazing ways to produce powerful and amazing results.  __Don't__! Instead write 2 queries and process them to fill one series each. Much simpler to understand. - To do it really well write a function that takes the year and a series name as parameters..

Comment: Also note: SQL knows no inherent ordering, so it is a mistake to rely on the records coming back in the order of their date/month. So you should either select the full date to use for the x-values or add an order clause!!

Comment: @TaW I Know what u mean but then ? when i will make function sorry i'm beginner can u help me how to generate graph from this query ?

Comment: To help you with a suitable query you should add at least some info about the actual database table the data come from.

Comment: @TaW database is manually entered .. so i want to make UCPVol each line refer to it's year